# Tracking User-Interaction for created User Interfaces

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt

Is there a general approach for *Tracking User-Interaction*? So that we can record how users interact with our Tools? Generally I am creating UI's with *Qt* and I would like to know in which order they are selecting stuff. Especially when the user is sending a Bug-Report I would like to know what buttons he pressed before.

I can imagine to track the events in Qt by overriding eventfilter

```
def eventfilter(event):
    eventTracker.add("user triggered event: " + event)
```

Is there a Library for such cases or an external tool that can be attached to the process?

Comment: Baad! You ask for a software recommandation, it isn't allowed here. But you can ask for a *solution*, which may or may not contain the name of a software. I suggest to reformulate your question fast and then nominate for reopen.

Comment: Not sure this fully fits your scenario, but it might help: http://www.ics.com/blog/using-google-analytics-monitor-qt-applications

Comment: This is definetly not a software recommandation, just let the question go for a day

Comment: This topic has two upvotes, and is put on hold.... thats bad moderation!